# How can I get a pointer to the first element of an std::string even if it is empty

Tags: c++, stdstring

How can I get a pointer to the first element of an non-const std::string even if it is empty.

I know for sure the string has a capacity greater than one, however, simply using

```
&my_string.front()
```

triggers a "out of range iterator" assertion failure because the string is empty.
Using member function

```
data()
```

doesn't fit too, because I want a pointer of type char*, not const char*. I guess I can perform a const_cast here, but that doesn't seem neat.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `&my_string[0]`? Do note that *any* indexing on an empty string leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want this? Sounds like a [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Comment: What are you expecting in case of empty string? Is testing the emptiness and then returning what you need not an option?

Comment: `&my_string[0]` will return a valid address.    It is not a particularly useful pointer though since using it to modify the character at that address will give undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Mikitori I am using the string as a buffer.

Comment: Simply use `c_str()`.

Comment: @Peter Pointers to distinct elements of a `std::string` (or a `std::vector` for that matter) are perfectly fine to dereference and use to modify the value the pointer is pointing to, as long as the pointer is valid. That last thing is important, since both `std::string` and `std::vector` can reallocate their contents leading to all pointers and iterators becoming invalid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, [you are not permitted to modify the value pointed-to by `&my_string[my_string.size()]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.access-2).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _"Do note that any indexing on an empty string leads to undefined behavior."_ Again, no (same reference)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - `&mystring[mystring.size()]` returns the address of a char with value zero that follows the string data.   Modifying it gives undefined behaviour.   It's a bit of an oddity, I agree.

Comment: Everybody, `&my_string[0]` is valid on a ***non-empty*** string. You can modify that character (through the pointer) as much as you want. `my_string[my_string.size()]` is ***out of bounds*** and I know that, and since an empty string have a size of zero it follows that any indexing on an empty string is out of bounds and will thus lead to UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Click on the link I provided for you. `my_string[my_string.size()]` is _not_ out of bounds, but it _is_ (very) special (and weird). As such, `&my_string[0]` is valid here too.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - recent versions of the standard have a specific provision that says otherwise - as linked by Lightness Races in Orbit.   That clause is an odd pandering to some language lawyers, but it's in the standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah, the phrasing is a little odd to me but I think I see the point now. It's weird requirement though IMO, why have a pointer to a non-const `char` is you can't modify the `char` to anything but `char()`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why have an "end" iterator that you can't dereference? This is an "end" iterator, but with the added feature that we can actually dereference it, and will always get a `CharT()` for our trouble (as long as we don't try to modify that value) - this added feature is presumably to make some interactions with C code easier. It's also linked in to the guarantees of `c_str()` and `data()` being null-terminated, now that neither requires a buffer copy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh that's simple, because it's really an iterator to one element beyond the last valid element. Dereferencing that would quite naturally be out of bounds. For a string (or any homogeneous and contiguous container), modifying a valid in-bounds character through a pointer is quite natural I think.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `c_str` is const too

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It depends whether you're looking at the string (for which this magic terminator _is_ out of bounds already, just like any one-past-the-end iterator in any C++ container) or the underlying buffer (which I'm trying to ignore because that's an abstraction leak - unfortunately doing so is difficult because this whole feature is an abstraction leak :D)

Answer (score 4):

To have `string::data()` returning `char*` you have to upgrade to C++17, unfortunately. const_cast'ing result of `data()` might be viable option if you really need to have write access to underlying data.

Comment: data() returns char* in C++17? I've never heard of that.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li A quick visit to [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) is what you need

Answer (score 3):

Although `front()` will throw here, `my_string[my_string.size()]` is nowadays deemed valid — you can't do much with it, but [you *can* take and store its address](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) (so, `&my_string[0]`).

However, there's only questionable value in doing so. So you could probably assume that the first bunch of character insertions (up to the current capacity) won't practically invalidate your pointer, but your code will be of unclear correctness, as [we are specifically told by *string.require¶4* not to rely on it](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.require-4):

> References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a `basic_­string` sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that `basic_­string` object:
>
> - as an argument to any standard library function taking a reference to non-const `basic_­string` as an argument.
> - Calling non-const member functions, except `operator[]`, `at`, `data`, `front`, `back`, `begin`, `rbegin`, `end`, and `rend`.

So it's really not assured that the special "empty" buffer pointed-to will really be the same one eventually used to store a real string (though that buffer will also be guaranteed null-terminated in the same way). Certainly once you go above the capacity all bets are completely off, and do you really want to be tracking that event?

It really sounds like `std::string` is not what you want, or that you should be accessing `data()` *as and when* rather than calling it once then storing the resulting pointer.

If you're interacting with some C API that needs to store this pointer, I would switch to something else, perhaps a fixed-length character buffer. On the C++ side you can still make use of [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) to do pleasing (read-only) things with your C-like character buffer, so you wouldn't lose any of that.

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

void OkayCApiStoreThisThen(const char*) {}

static constexpr const size_t BUF_SIZE = 255;
char silly_buf[BUF_SIZE] = {};

int main()
{
    // Sadface
    OkayCApiStoreThisThen(silly_buf);

    // Happyface
    std::string_view str(silly_buf, sizeof(silly_buf));

    silly_buf[0] = 'l';
    silly_buf[1] = 'o';
    silly_buf[2] = 'l';
    silly_buf[3] = '!';

    std::cout << str.substr(0, 3) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Ultimately I can't say much more without hearing about your use case and _real_ requirements, which you neglected to provide...

Comment: I use a string as buffer, calling some function that requires input of the form (void *, size_t).

Comment: @JohnZ.Li So why do you not just keep a string as normal and send it `.data(), .size()`, and do nothing if the string is empty?

Comment: Because data() gives const char *., the caller needs to write to the buffer.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li It only did so until C++17; regardless, you could always use `&my_string[0]` if the string is non-empty. The key is to do nothing if it's not (but, as explored, since C++11 you actually can still do that). I'm not really getting why the standard technique is a problem. Perhaps you can explain the requirements in more detail.

Comment: I know this thread a year old but doesn't data() create a new char array from the std:string to point to? If you're already using a string_view because the string your dealing with is very large, wouldn't a pointer to the first element be a nice thing to have around rather than creating a new char array that data() gives you a pointer to? Or am I wrong and data() doesn't create a new char array each time?